# linq to dictionary cannot implicity convert type

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

iam new in linq, i want to convert linq result to dictionary, but i get an error.

this is my c# code :

```
var q = from abs in db.TT_ABSENCEs
        join emp in db.TT_EMPLOYEEs on abs.Employee_NIP equals emp.Employee_NIP
        where
        Convert.ToDateTime(abs.ReceivedTime).Day == DateTime.Now.Day
        && Convert.ToDateTime(abs.ReceivedTime).Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                && Convert.ToDateTime(abs.ReceivedTime).Year == DateTime.Now.Year
        select new { abs.ReceivedTime, abs.Employee_NIP, abs.AbsenceTime, abs.GeoLoc, abs.statusAbsence, emp.Employee_Name };


Dictionary<String, TT_ABSENCE> _dict =
    q.ToDictionary(abs => abs.Employee_NIP, abs => abs.statusAbsence);
```

this is my error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,AnonymousType#1>`' to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,DataAccess.TT_ABSENCE>`'

how to convert linq result to dictionary?

Comment: Replace this `select new { abs.ReceivedTime, abs.Employee_NIP, abs.AbsenceTime, abs.GeoLoc, abs.statusAbsence, emp.Employee_Name }` with this `select abs`

Comment: still error Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: oh okay, its works :D

Comment: but i cant get employeeName with one query, how to get it?

Comment: That wasn't what you asked for.

Comment: okay hmm may be i ask for to convert this join query result from linq to dictionary, but thanks

Comment: Not helpful. Create a new question asking exactly what you want to achieve...I based my answer off of the last line, where you wanted a dictionary of type `Dictionary<String, TT_ABSENCE>` where the string was `Employee_NIP`. Given you clearly don't know Linq very well, we can't figure out your intention as the compiler can't figure out your intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var q = from abs in db.TT_ABSENCEs
        join emp in db.TT_EMPLOYEEs on abs.Employee_NIP equals emp.Employee_NIP
        where
        Convert.ToDateTime(abs.ReceivedTime).Day == DateTime.Now.Day
        && Convert.ToDateTime(abs.ReceivedTime).Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                && Convert.ToDateTime(abs.ReceivedTime).Year == DateTime.Now.Year
        select abs;


Dictionary<String, TT_ABSENCE> _dict =  q.ToDictionary(abs => abs.Employee_NIP);
```